# Is DRBD split-brain handler called only when after-sb-Xpri is set to disconnect?

Tags: drbd, splitbrain

I wanted to run a script if a split brain is detected. In the documentation, it is mentioned that we can do that by providing the path of the script like

```
resource <resource>
  handlers {
    split-brain <handler>;
    ...
  }
```

But, below that, for the after-sb-0pri configuration, it is mentioned that

> disconnect: Do not recover automatically, simply invoke the
> split-brain handler script (if configured), drop the connection and
> continue in disconnected mode.

So, my question is that, will the configured script be run only when after-sb-0pri is set to disconnect, or will that run for any set value

Document Link: https://linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/users-guide-drbd-8-4/#s-configure-split-brain-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRBD should invoke the split-brain handler whenever a split-brain is detected. I.E. Anything that would log a `Split-Brain detected ...` in the system/kernel logs. The documentation attempts to explain this at the beginning of chapter 5.17.1 with:

> DRBD invokes the split-brain handler, if configured, at any time split
> brain is *detected*.

Additionally, `disconnect` is the default value for `after-sb-0pri`. So, even if not explicitly set that will still be the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was only confused because it was explicitly mentioned that the split-brain handler will be invoked when after-sb-pri is set to disconnect